# Is there a constraint in the Nurse Scheduling Problem that limits the number of consecutive shifts?

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools

Following the nurse scheduling example from the google OR tools tutorial (https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling), I'm trying to add more constraints to the problem.

For example, there are 24 shifts to meet 24hrs of manning in a clinic; (1) nurses cannot work more than 4 consecutive shifts without have at least a 1 shift break, and (2) nurses need to sleep for the length of 8 shifts after every 16 shifts.

How would one go about implementing these two constraints?

If it's not possible in OR-tools, is there another way where this can be implemented?

I could only tinker with a constraint that is cumulative:

## Each nurse works at most 6 days in a week.

```
for j in range(num_nurses):
    solver.Add(solver.Sum([shifts[(j, i)] > 0
                           for i in range(num_days)]) <= 6)
```

Appreciate if someone could guide me with adding on the two constraints! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in this example.
Please have a look at a more complete shift scheduling example in:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

Comment: Thank you. I've actually read the more detailed link before but didn't find the comments as intuitive as the documentation in the simpler problem.

Is def add_soft_sequence_constraint the part for constraint (1)
and def add_soft_sum_constraint the part for constraint (2)?

Comment: add_soft_sequence is what you want.